# Interview Scheduling Algorithm, 1 candidate and N interviewers

Tags: algorithm, optimization

**Problem**

We have 'n' number of interviewers and their free-busy slots. We want to schedule interviews of a candidate with these 'n' interviewers one by one. Interviews can be in any order.

Approach 1: First come first serve

Start with the first interviewer

1. Take the interviewer and create an interview schedule based on its free-busy slot.
2. Then take the next interviewer and repeat step 1.
   But with this approach, we can miss out on some cases.

Approach 2: Greedy algorithm

1. Sort the interviewers on the basis of the number of free slots available in their free-busy schedules.
2. Create an interview schedule for the interviewer with the least number of free-busy slots.
3. Repeat step 2 for the next interviewer.

Is there any more optimized/better approach for this problem?

Comment: Does "one by one" mean the selected interview times must form a contiguous block? Are there variable costs for anything or just either can schedule or not?

Comment: @גלעדברקן no, "one by one" here means that at a time only 1 interviewer can interview the candidate.

Comment: are you having trouble making a feasible solution because folks are real busy or are you trying to optimize something like minimum makespan for the candidate (minimize time between first and last)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can re-cast this problem in terms of graph theory:

For each interviewer, generate a node. For each interview slot, generate a node too. Now create edges between interviewer nodes and slot nodes for those combinations where the interviewer is available for that slot. This will give you a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).

The goal now is to find a [maximum cardinality matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching), i.e. a matching of interviewers to slots for as many interviewers as possible. Hence, if a full solution is not possible, it will even give you a partial schedule. Common algorithms for this are the [Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) (or [Edmonds-Karp Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)) and the [Hopcroft-Karp Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).